# how to get the height of an Image in react native?

Tags: react-native

How to get the height of an image , I found getSize() function in the documentation but I can't figure out why it didn't work with me its shows error saying

> can't find variable height

```
 const { OffersTitle,imag,link} = props.offer;
   getImagez({imag});
```

in  my code I am destructuring props to get link of my image so if I alert(imag) it will pops up

> 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR11n.jpg'

and in my imagez() Funtion this how it is my code :

```
getImagez = ({imag}) => {
 const imgz = Image.getSize(imag, {height} );
 const hgth = { imgz };
return hgth ;

 }
```

could you please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get both height and width and check if it is working or not

```
Image.getSize(imag, (width, height)=>{console.log(height)});;
```

As you can check in source code of `Image`, it will accept success and failure callback and in case of success it will return width and height

[image]

Comment: thanks for ur help its working , but  with my code it pops up [object Object] const imgz = Image.getSize(imag, (width, height)=>{height});
  alert (imgz);

Comment: try it `Image.getSize(imag, (width, height)=>alert(JSON.stringify(height))); `